# sh - unexpected token in password is causing error

Tags: linux, shell, sh, sshpass

I am writing a script to create a directory and download an artifact in that directory on a remote machine using `sshpass`. A small portion of it is :

```
userCredential='^&$&]h4HZ;RFc$4w(289K(XZxbe}G'
sshpass -p $userCredential ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $username@$machineUrl << EOF 
echo $userCredential | sudo -S mkdir -p /usr/local/downloadedWar$timestamp
EOF
```

The above fails with the following error:

```
Last failed login: Tue Feb 15 10:41:36 UTC 2022 from <some hostname> on ssh:notty
There were 2 failed login attempts since the last successful login.
-bash: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `289K'
-bash: line 1: `echo ^&$&]h4HZ;RFc$4w(289K(XZxbe}G | sudo -S mkdir -p /usr/local/downloadedWar2022-02-16-04:37:00'
```

Is there anyway to escape the password to handle this situation ?

Note: userCredential is part of user input. The value in userCredential can be anything

Comment: try escape `$` with `$$`. but the error says 'near unexpected token 289K', maybe some other issue.

Comment: Yeah you are right , could be something else too. Also I can't escape explicity as userCredential is part of user input. I have updated the description and the title too

Answer (score 0):

When you use the variable try to put then in double quote.

```
sshpass -p "$userCredential"...
echo "$userCredential"...
```